# XML Error in Eclipse while viewing Graphical Layout of Xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

This is the error I'm getting in my layout XML files:

```
Exception raised during rendering: 0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- View (Change to android.view.View, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

My Xml File is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_view_main_lin_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/search_view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_view_row_size" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_ico"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/search_text_view"
            android:textColor="#FF37200e"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_left_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchgray_ico"
            android:drawablePadding="05dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:hint="@string/search_text_view"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="35dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_left_menu"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancel_search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/search_edit_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cross"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/featured_lin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_view_row_size"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/featured_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/featured_text_view"
        android:textColor="#FF37200e"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_left_menu" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/featured_text_view"
        android:src="@drawable/featured_ico" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_featured_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/favorites_lin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_view_row_size"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorites_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/favorites_text_view"
        android:textColor="#FFb2661A"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_view_left_menu" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favorites_text_view"
        android:src="@drawable/favorites_active_ico" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_divider" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

I'm using Eclipse **Juno**. Currently my project Build target is **android 4.1**. I've tried by lowering the API level also but it doesn't  help me.

Due to this I'm not able to see the graphical layout of my XML files.
Please anybody help me.

Comment: Please post your xml layout for more helps

Comment: are you using any image as src to some of the view in your layout.

Comment: may be issue of custom obj if you are using in xml file

Comment: @Abhinav Yes, I'm using the image src for one of my image view.

Comment: try removing that. I hope it will fix that. I don't know the exact reason but it happened with me too, and on removing the imageView it was working fine..
If its the case need not to worry
It has to do something with the eclipse. in my case it has started behaving normally on its on without any change.

Answer (score 8):

There is a mismatch between your target SDK version and your Graphical Layout target, should be an easy fix.

If you don't know it off the top of your head, you can get your Android SDK version for your project from right-clicking on your project name, going to Properties, selecting "Android", and looking for the test in the "platform" column for the row with a checkmark.

Then in the Graphical Layout for your XML file, in the top right in between the Locale selector and the Create button is a drop-down for Android versions. Change this to match the one for your project, and the errors should go away the graphical preview will render correctly.

Comment: Thanks, But my both versions are same and still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

its very semple

all you have to do is change android version used to render layout in eclipse

[android version used to render layout Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEooW.png)

hope that help you.